# How to create web component for third party website with Vue 3.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Recently I migrated my web application to Vue 3 which is implemented with Vue 2 earlier. This app is using as a web component for other websites with different frameworks. In vue 2 once the application is build as web component it is nicely generating the the compressed version of js files and can add to other website direcly. In vue 2 I used below command to build the web component.

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name widget-v2 ./src/components/EntryComponent.vue
```

It is generating the js files and we can simply import that files to other website and add the web component tag like : `<widget-v2></widget-v2>` to html and it works.

But once I migrated the app to Vue 3 when I try to build the app as web component it is showing the below error.

[image]

I search through internet and found out we have to change the build command like below.

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name widget-v3 src/components/EntryComponent.vue
```

But the issue is once the js files are generated and when I import the js to other web page and add the tag same as easier it does not work.

[image]

I checked the demo.html how the widget added in there. But it is different from earlier than Vue2 version which is added like this. But we can pass props in this method which I tried and generated errors.

[image]

My question is how can we add the web component as simply as in Vue 2 when we use Vue 3.

Comment: We can use vue3 custom elements to fix this issue.